# Node Net refuses connection no matter what on learnyounode

Tags: node.js

I continuously get the following error:

> ✗ Error connecting to localhost:20496: connect ECONNREFUSED

*note:* The local host number is always changing.

On **cloud9.ide** the error happens *before* a timeout, and on **my computer** the error happens *after* a timeout. (it happens in both areas so I think it's a local host problem)

The code I'm using is exactly as follows:

```
var net = require('net');
function zero(i) {
  return (i < 10 ? '0' : '') + i;
}
function now () {
  var d = new Date();
  return d.getFullYear() + '-' + zero(d.getMonth()) + '-'
    + zero(d.getDate()) + ' ' + zero(d.getHours()) + ':'
    + zero(d.getMinutes());
}

var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.error(function(){
        console.log("Error");
    });
  socket.end("FOUND:"+now() + '\n');
}).listen(8000);
```

I don't understand why the `net` module doesn't work and the `http` module did. I feel like it has something to do with the port being listened to, but I changed it to **3306** and there were no differences in the output.

I believe I'm running the latest version of node and learnyounode, and my OS is widnows7.

versions:

- Npm:2.11.2
- Node:0.12.5

Comment: How do you run your script? `node script.js`?

Comment: @Michelem I've run my script in the node repl like you just said, but I've mainly been doing it though nodechools `learynounode run program.js`

Answer (score 2):

Could you try this (taken from the docs) and post back the results:

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(c) { //'connection' listener
  console.log('client connected');
  c.on('end', function() {
    console.log('client disconnected');
  });
  c.write('hello\r\n');
  c.pipe(c);
});
server.listen(8124, function() { //'listening' listener
  console.log('server bound');
});
```

And you would eventually test it like this:

```
telnet localhost 8124
```

> To listen on the socket /tmp/echo.sock the third line from the last would just be changed to
>
> `server.listen('/tmp/echo.sock', function() { //'listening' listener`
>
> Use nc to connect to a UNIX domain socket server:
>
> `nc -U /tmp/echo.sock`

Comment: Looks like that worked... I did `node program.js` and my console, after typing `telnet localhost 8124` got: "server bound .. client connected ..." my telnet received "hello" .. I closed it  and my console got "client disconnected"

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew so my guesses are the problem is either with the port your using (which you even have tried 3306 - but please note that this latter port is the MySQL default port! So make sure your nothing is running on this port.), or there something wring with the socket you're using.

Comment: I checked the same thing using port 8000(with telnet) and that worked just as well. And this error only seems to happen on the **learnyounode** tutorial!

Comment: At least with your solution I was able to see that my program was working. Just don't know how to work with with learnyounode yet.